How to make CALCULATE measure for last date exists before date in current row?
I got this table:




rounds_bot_date
values




1
2024-04-09
10


2
2024-04-10
20


0
2024-04-11
30


3
2024-04-15
40


4
2024-04-16
50


5
2024-04-17
60



How to make CALCULATE(SUM('table'[values]) with filter for last existing date before current date in row?
For example for 15.04 I want get value 30, for 10.04 - 10.

I solved problem this way.
Cause I use data from Postgres, I use this query to add new column:
select  rounds_bot_date, 
        lead(rounds_bot_date) over(order by rounds_bot_date) as next_date,
        values
from    rounds r

So I get this table:




rounds_bot_date
next_date
values




0
2024-04-09
2024-04-10
10


1
2024-04-10
2024-04-11
20


2
2024-04-11
2024-04-15
30


3
2024-04-15
2024-04-16
40


4
2024-04-16
2024-04-17
50


5
2024-04-17

60



I add new relationship between calendar_date and table[next_date].
My measure:
_2_2_values_prev_day = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('table'[values]),
    USERELATIONSHIP('_calendar'[Date], 'values'[next_date])
)

Result (in Power BI it looks a bit different):




rounds_bot_date
next_date
values_prev_date
values




0
2024-04-09
2024-04-10
nan
10


1
2024-04-10
2024-04-11
10
20


2
2024-04-11
2024-04-15
20
30


3
2024-04-15
2024-04-16
30
40


4
2024-04-16
2024-04-17
40
50


5
2024-04-17

50
60



In Power BI:

Maybe there's way to make it all with DAX or M coding and I just don't figure it out.
P. S. I can make same thing by adding 2 index columns (from 0 and 1). And make self merge table by this indexes.
But in this case I think find prev date with SQL lead window function will works faster.

Update:
Measure = 
VAR x = MAX('Table'[rounds_bot_date])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[values]), 
    REMOVEFILTERS(), 
    'Table'[rounds_bot_date] < x
)

As a a measure.
Measure = 
VAR x = MAX('Table'[rounds_bot_date])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Table'[values]), 
    REMOVEFILTERS(), 
    'Table'[rounds_bot_date] < x
)



I need add this logic to  CALCULATE + SUM. This table just example. Making VAR doesn't works.

I'll upvote, but I found my own decision of problem.

Measure from update calculating cumulative sum, not sum for previous existing date. =/
